# How to register a new user using asp.net(C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, createuserwizard

I want to make a function to register a new user without using CreateUserWizard. How could I change my code to allow this?

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="registerUser.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<html>
  <head runat="server">
    <title>LLLY网上书店 - 注册</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <section class="register">
        <h1>LLLY网上书店 - 注册新用户</h1>
        <form method="post" action="index.html" runat="server">
          <div class="reg_section personal_info">
            <h3>个人信息</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" value="" placeholder="用户名"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" placeholder="电子邮件地址"></asp:TextBox>
          </div>
          <div class="reg_section password">
            <h3>用户密码</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" placeholder="请输入密码"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="confirmPwd" runat="server" placeholder="确认密码"></asp:TextBox>
            <input type="password" name="confirm" value="" placeholder="确认密码">--%>
          </div>
          <div class="reg_section password">
            <h3>地区</h3>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
              <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:TextBox ID="textarea" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" placeholder="家庭住址"></asp:TextBox>
          </div>
          <p class="terms">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
              我同意  <a href="http://www.imomen.com/">LLLY网上书店</a>&nbsp;注册准入原则
              </label>
          </p>
          <p class="submit">
            <asp:Button ID="commit" runat="server" Text="注册" onclick="commit_Click"></asp:Button>
          </p>
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. :) I recommend you alter this question to say what the code you included does and what you have tried. Thats the standard question format.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please note that here is site thats try to focus on errors that appears as you try to make something. Now also note that programmers hate to take some code and make it work, they 1000 prefer to write it from beginning... Now your question is not good as it is at the moment and the full solution to what you looking for is here: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-user-accounts-cs   . Please try to focus on specific problems and not on general requests if you wish to get more help. And first search a lot on the internet spend some days, then ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not so simple and you can find a fully tutorial with source code and details on asp.net site:

[Creating User Accounts (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-user-accounts-cs)

Also you can read the article about:[Understanding ASP.NET Roles and Membership - A Beginner's Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342061/Understanding-ASP-NET-Roles-and-Membership-A-Begin)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create user by code you can use one of overload method of Create User in Membership class.

MSDN : [Membership.CreateUser Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.createuser.aspx)

```
MembershipCreateStatus status;
var user = Membership.CreateUser(username.Text, password.Text, email.Text, null, null, true, out status);
```